# Auto Batch Process - Trim, change bit rate and then normalize wav files via sox on Windows

Tags: batch, wav, sox

I would like to batch process wav files in a folder:

1. Firstly trimming the files to 5secs and placing the trimmed files in a folder called "Trim5s", then
2. Changing the bit rate on the trimmed files (that is in the folder "Trim5s") and saving the new bit rate files derived from the trimmed files in Step 1 above to a folder called "16bit" and then
3. Normalize the new trimmed + new bitrate files to -1 that is in the "16bit" folder derived in Step 2 above and saving the normalied + trimmed files + new bitrate files to a folder "Norm-1".

This is my folder structure:

```
MainFolder
   |____file1.wav
   |____file2.wav
   |____Trim5s
           |____file1_trim5s.wav
           |____file2_trim5s.wav
           |____16bit
                  |____file1_trim5s_16bit.wav
                  |____file2_trim5s_16bit.wav
                  |____Norm-1
                         |____file1_trim5s_16bit_Norm-1.wav
                         |____file2_trim5s_16bit_Norm-1.wav
```

Currently I do the steps manually each time for each step.  Here are the Windows `cmd` commands:

Step 1: Trim files to  secs:

```
for %i in (*.wav) do sox -S "%i" "Trim5s\%~ni_trim5.wav" trim 0 5
```

I then manually change the directory to "Trim5s" and run the second step:

Step 2: Change bit depth to 16bits in the "Trim5s" folder:

```
for %i in (*.wav) do sox -S "%i" -b 16 "16bit\%~ni_16bit.wav"
```

Then I manually change the directory again to the folder "16bit" and run the third step:

Step 3: Normalize files in the 16bit folder:

```
for %i in (*.wav) do sox -S --norm=-1 "%i" "Norm-1\%~ni_norm-1.wav"
```

Is there a way to automate this process where I can automatically do all 3 process?  That is, convert the three manual steps given above to a nested loop?   Can the nested loop be accomplished or is there a better approach to carry out the 3 tasks mentioned above automatically from the MainFolder?

This is what I tried so far:

```
for %i in (*.wav) do sox -S "%i" "Trim5s\%~ni_trim-pt75.wav" trim 0 0.75 & 
cd Trim5s for %i in (*.wav) do sox -S "%i" -b 16 "16bit\%~ni_16bit.wav" & 
cd Norm-1 for %i in (*.wav) do sox -S --norm=-1 "%i" "Norm-1\%~ni_norm-1.wav"
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```bat
@echo off && cd /d "%~dp0"

2>nul mkdir "%~dp0Trim5s\16bit" "%~dp0Trim5s\Norm-1"
set "_sox=C:\Program Files (x86)\sox-14-4-2\sox.exe"

for %%i in ("%~dp0*.wav")do "%_sox%" -S "%%~fi" "%~dp0Trim5s\%%~ni_trim-pt75.wav" trim 0 0.75
for %%i in ("%~dp0Trim5s\*.wav")do "%_sox%" -S "%%~fi" -b 16 "%~dp0Trim5s\16bit\%%~ni_16bit.wav"
for %%i in ("%~dp0Trim5s\16bit\*.wav")do "%_sox%" -S --norm=-1 "%%~fi" "%~dp0Trim5s\Norm-1\%%~ni_norm-1.wav"
```

---

You don't need `cd folder` and `&`:

```bat
for %i in (*.wav) do sox -S "%i" "Trim5s\%~ni_trim-pt75.wav" trim 0 0.75 & 
cd Trim5s for %i in (*.wav) do sox -S "%i" -b 16 "16bit\%~ni_16bit.wav"  & 
cd Norm-1  for %i in (*.wav) do sox -S --norm=-1 "%i" "Norm-1\%~ni_norm-1.wav"
```

Use `"%~dp0"` and `"%~dp0+Path"`

```bat
"%~dp0*.wav"
"%~dp0Trim5s\*.wav"
"%~dp0Trim5s\16bit\*.wav"
```

- **Obs.:** Assuming your bath is in the `MainFolder` folder, if not, replace:

```bat
rem :: %~dp0 
rem :: C:\Full\Path\To\MainFolder\
```

- ```bat
  @echo off && cd /d "C:\Full\Path\To\MainFolder\"
    
  2>nul mkdir "%cd%\Trim5s\16bit" "%cd%\Trim5s\Norm-1"
  set "_sox=C:\Program Files (x86)\sox-14-4-2\sox.exe"
    
  for %%i in ("%cd%\*.wav")do "%_sox%" -S "%%~fi" "%~dp0Trim5s\%%~ni_trim-pt75.wav" trim 0 0.75
  for %%i in ("%cd%\Trim5s\*.wav")do "%_sox%" -S "%%~fi" -b 16 "%~dp0Trim5s\16bit\%%~ni_16bit.wav"
  for %%i in ("%cd%\Trim5s\16bit\*.wav")do "%_sox%" -S --norm=-1 "%%~fi" "%~dp0Trim5s\Norm-1\%%~ni_norm-1.wav"
  ```

---

---

- Some further reading:

  [√] **[set /?](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html)**

  [√] **[mkdir /?](https://ss64.com/nt/md.html)**

  [√] **[For Loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for_d.html)**

  [√] **[For /F Loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html)**

  [√] **[What does %~dp0 mean, and how does it work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5034076/what-does-dp0-mean-and-how-does-it-work)**

  [√] **[Understanding start, 2>nul, cmd, and other symbols in a batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19598997/understanding-start-2nul-cmd-and-other-symbols-in-a-batch-file#:%7E:text=A%20command%20can%20output%20to,So%20nothing%20will%20be%20outputted.&text=Line%204%3A%20hard%20to%20tell%20without%20seeing%20rest%20of%20script.)**

Comment: Works nothing less than perfect!  Thanks for your wonderful and elegant code.  Perfection!

Comment: Thank you too for test